# Regex for only allowing letters, numbers, space, commas, periods?

Tags: php, regex

I am clueless with regex as it is complicated for me. I am working with a program that limits input from users based on a regex. I am currently after a regex that will only let the user input:

```
A-Z and a-z
0-9
.
,
!
?
```

So basically anything in a typical paragraph or web article.

The program states "Enter a regular expression which entered text must match (evaluated with preg_match, using s and i flags) for it to be valid."

I have tried this regex with no success and I am currently searching for others to try.

```
 '/^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ]*$/'
```

It should allow a simple sentence such as

> "HI my name is John! I like to eat apples, oranges, and grapes. Will you eat with me?

Comment: `.` is a special character. You need to escape it: `\.`

Comment: No, `.` doesn't need escaping inside the `[]` character class.

Comment: looks like you forgot `!` and `?`.

Comment: What input string are you testing the pattern you posted above with? It is basically correct per your criteria, except that that it permits a zero-length string and omits `!?`

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the ! and ? after I tested that string as I forgot those. That is the updated string which I need a regex to work with that.

Comment: `*` is zero or more, trying changing it to `+` (one or more).

Comment: So your input string is literally the multiline block of characters at the top of your post? You would need the `/m` modifier to match that with its line breaks, plus add `!?` to your `[]`

Comment: Also, it would appear that you need to be able to match a `-` hyphen. Add that to the _end_ of your `[]` group.

Comment: Dont need line breaks. This is used for a single 1 line sentence. The string I provided was an example. I need to be able to have upper/lower letters, numbers, and puncuation. Trying to limit the ability for users to enter injectable code into this userbox.

Comment: Exactly as you have it, `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,?! ]*$/', $s)` works correctly with your provided sentence.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`^[\.a-zA-Z0-9,!? ]*$`

is what the regex is, it works, see example website to test regex.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use '/^[\w .,!?]+$/'

The alphanumeric \w metacharacter is equivalent to the character range [A-Za-z0-9_]

eg:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $messageErr = "Message cant be empty";
  } elseif (preg_match('/^[\w .,!?()]+$/', $message) === false){
    $messageErr = "Only aA-zZ09.,!?_ are allowed";
  } else {
    $message = data($_POST["message"]);
  }
}
function data($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
# Do something with $message
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a-z or 0-9. 
`"[\w,.!?]"`
should work.